# DLL-based application framework with bi-directional interfaces (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, com, interface

## Solved

`this` wasn't the problem, since it's being implicitly cast to `IFramework` anyway.

I was concerned it may have to do with my methods not returning `HRESULT`, or with my stubby implementations of `IUnknown::QueryInterface`, but the real problem was merely a compiler setting that had overridden several macros I needed for common calling conventions (perhaps I should have included them in the question). This had corrupted the stack.

It's interesting though, that it worked will all compilers I tested, even without implementing IUnknown at all - a little research suggests that all serious Windows compilers handle abstract C++ interfaces the same way - namely as a virtual table specifically to be used as a COM interface.

---

Hi. I'm trying to create an extensible application framework. My basic concept is this:

[image: Framework Schematics]

The "Framework" box will build an .exe whereas the multiple "Plugin" boxes will build .dll files.

However, my implementation is apparently flawed. I have an idea what's the problem, but I'm running out of workarounds. I've done it exactly like this with .NET projects, but the problem I have now didn't apply to the C# environment.

Consider these interfaces:

```
class IFramework
{
public:
    virtual void FrameworkMethod() = 0;
};

class IPlugin
{
public:
    virtual void PluginMethod() = 0;
    virtual void PluginCallbackTest() = 0;
    virtual void SetFramework(IFramework *framework) = 0;
};
```

Implementation of the framework:

```
class CFramework : IFramework
{
public:
    void FrameworkMethod(); // printf("FrameworkMethod");
    void DoSomething(); // this is the testbench basically, see below
};
```

And the implementation of the plugin:

```
class CPlugin : public IPlugin
{
    IFramework *Framework;
public:
    void PluginMethod(); // printf("PluginMethod");
    void PluginCallbackTest(); // Framework->FrameworkMethod();
    void SetFramework(IFramework *framework); // Framework = framework;
};
// plugin factory -> COM interface
extern "C" PLUGIN_API IPlugin *GetPlugin(); // return new CPlugin;
```

Now to demonstrate that this concept doesn't work:

```
void CFramework::DoSomething()
{
    HMODULE PluginHandle = LoadLibrary(...); // explicit linking
    auto GetPlugin = ((IPlugin *)(*)())GetProcAddress(...);
    IPlugin *plugin = GetPlugin();
    plugin->PluginMethod();
    // up until here everything's perfectly COM-compliant and works super
    plugin->SetFramework(this); // <-- that is the problem 
    plugin->PluginCallbackTest(); // <-- runtime crash if compiler differs
    FreeLibrary(PluginHandle);
}
```

The problem is that the `SetFramework(this)` doesn't work like COM. It's not that it just feels wrong to write it like this - I can't implement a working plugin with a compiler that differs from the one I used to build CFramework (runtime crashes).

Comment: `GetPlugin()` should presumably be returning a pointer?

Comment: @Ben Voigt yeah it does in my code -- typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow different compilers for the plug-ins from what you use for the app then you need to use COM exclusively across the boundary between app and plug-ins. That is precisely the problem that COM was designed to solve.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that imply that it's impossible to write it _bi-directionally_ like I intended? Since I cannot create a "framework factory" to be used by plugins. Or am I just completely off? If it is indeed not possible, is there a way to let plugins communicate with each other, and can they even use IFramework?

Comment: @dialer So long as you stick to COM interfaces and don't pass around objects you'll be fine. You haven't shown all your code though. I don't see IUnknown and I don't see any of the trappings that turn a C++ class into a COM object. I don't understand quite what your problem is but so long as you stick to COM then your design is sound. As I said, it's what COM was designed for.